# Unable to read csv file generated by Google Survey using Pandas

Tags: pandas, csv

I am just a few weeks into Python and data analytic. I am trying to analyze a data set of over 3000 responses generated by Google Survey for my company.

This is how the data set looks like:
[A first few rows of the data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUyX2.png)

```
 import pandas as pd
    data=pd.read_csv('Survey.csv')
```

I got the error of `"ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 6, saw 7".`

My guess is that some questions in the survey allow the users to pick multiple choices, which result in some cell in the csv file that store a list of values, instead of a value. Values in such list are separated by ','. A clear example is the value in the column of 'Paper_Comic_Genre' above.

Is there anyway I can read this csv file into Python then clean it there instead of doing the work in excel?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you try `data=pd.read_csv('Survey.csv', sep=';')`? I guess the data is separated by `;`. It is always a good idea to open your file in notepadd++ or any other text editor than in Excel to view.

Comment: try: `pd.read_csv('Survey.csv', error_bad_lines=False)`

Comment: Thanks both for your suggestion. I tried the error_bad_lines command but it did not work. This is what I tried: data=pd.read_csv('Survey.csv', sep=';', error_bad_lines=False)  // And this is what I got ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.

Answer (score 0):

if your parsing errors are at the last column, you can use this ad hoc function made by my own.

```
        import re
        #native module


        def tricky_parsing(number_of_sep,text):
            sep=[m.start() for m in re.finditer(',', text)]
        #array of each delimiter positions 


            tricky_list=[]
            tricky_list.append(text[:sep[0]])

            for i in range(1,number_of_sep):
                 tricky_list.append(text[sep[i-1]+1:sep[i]])

            tricky_list.append(text[sep[number_of_sep-1]+1:])

            return tricky_list

        #test
        tricky_parsing(4,"amara,boudib,test1,test3,,1,2,3")
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm stack over flow beginner.  I re-indent  my code for information. Thank's your information, i have never used the encoding option.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for all of the suggestion. Amara, your solution is just too complex for me to understand :D . I tried it and got an error of "index out of range".
This code finally works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Survey.csv', sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
data.info()
```

I finally figured out that the problem is caused by unicode issues. Regarding the sep =',', I have to do trial and error as I don't know which delimiter (',' or ';' or '\t') to use. I am using Mac thus having no access to notepadd++. Sublime Text does not give a hint.

The result:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5086 entries, 0 to 5085
Data columns (total 43 columns):
```